# Coil sound when battery charger is idle

Tags: battery-charging, switch-mode-power-supply, coil, sound

Why is there a noise from the coil in the circuit when the phone charger is idle?

Comment: (a) Because the switching regulator has gone into burst mode (by design) or (b) the device is faulty.

Comment: @Andyaka Sir, if there is a faulty thing what can it be? How to fix this design? To get a silent charger, how should it be designed? Thanks for your sincere ans.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why is there a noise from the coil in the circuit when the phone charger is idle?

This is because the switching supply circuit does not need to deliver much current.  As a result, it "skips" pulses, which we can hear.

Normally the switcher operates at a frequency outside our range of hearing (such as 50kHz.)  To operate at minimum "on" time at that frequency, a certain amount of current must be drawn from it.  When the drawn current goes below this level, the switcher must "turn off" for longer than the normal operating frequency, which seems like a reduction in that frequency to us.  When the time between pulses gets below 20kHz, we start to hear noise emission.  Can sound like a "hiss", "static", a "tone", even "fast clicking."

There are several modes or ways in which a switcher can handle low-current operation such as pulse-skipping, pulse-frequency-modulation, etc.  All of these modes involve slowing down the switching frequency in some way, which can be audible.

Only two things can be done to silence a loud switcher:

1. Introduce a binding agent (lacquer, conformal, potting compound (even under a vacuum) etc.) into the vibrating component(s) to physically reduce movement and thus audible noise.  Care must be taken though, as this will cause the components to operate hotter, since the addition of the covering material acts like a blanket and thermally insulates it.
2. Use a different switcher or engineer a more suitable one from scratch.  There are many reference switcher designs and options available, but honestly the details get quite complex, especially when optimizing for lowest-noise.  Other components can emit audible noise also, so the problem isn't limited to the inductor/transformer.